# (ZK 7) Auto fill no binding my data (MVVM and composer)

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, zk, autofill

I have a kind of bug with zk 7 with auto fill of chrome :(

Auto fill fills the fields in my web page (textbox) but the fields of my view-model stay empty with chrome.

For example, with an address form autofilled all data is null in my viewmodel (not in my textbox on the webpage)

If I simulate an event 'onChange' my binding works.

(zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$idOfMyTextBox'),"onChange",{'value':'test!!','start':6})) )

The problem is the same in a new zk project with one mvvm page.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Thanks for you help :)

Edit : An Exemple

I write my name and with Chrome by auto fill other fields are completed.

[Screen of form auto filled](http://hpics.li/10d06ed)

And the result is :

Name : Pigeon
First name : null
Address : null
Postal code : null
City : null

Zul

```
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul"
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd">

<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.enriquepigeon.TestZk.MyViewModel')">

    <label value="Name" />
    <textbox value="@bind(vm.nom)" />
    <h:br />

    <label value="First name" />
    <textbox value="@bind(vm.prenom)" />
    <h:br />

    <label value="Address" />
    <textbox value="@bind(vm.adresse)" />
    <h:br />

    <label value="Postal code" />
    <textbox value="@bind(vm.codePostal)" />
    <h:br />

    <label value="City" />
    <textbox value="@bind(vm.ville)" />
    <h:br />

    <button label="launch" onClick="@command('launch')" />

</window>
```

/zk>

My view model

```
public class MyViewModel {

private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String ville;
private String adresse;
private String codePostal;

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public String getVille() {
    return ville;
}

public void setVille(String ville) {
    this.ville = ville;
}

public String getAdresse() {
    return adresse;
}

public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
    this.adresse = adresse;
}

public String getCodePostal() {
    return codePostal;
}

public void setCodePostal(String codePostal) {
    this.codePostal = codePostal;
}

@Command
public void launch(){
    System.out.println("Name : "+nom);
    System.out.println("First name : "+prenom);
    System.out.println("Address : "+adresse);
    System.out.println("Postal code : "+codePostal);
    System.out.println("City : "+ville);
}
```

}

May be a configuration on zk.xml for force zk to reading the dom ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to save your data from form to view model is to separate the bind from your zul
example for the first name textbox:

`<textbox value="@load(vm.prenom) @save(vm.prenom, before='launch')" />`

if you do this for all your textboxes, you will spare alot of client/server comunications and I think it'll work for your case

Greets

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.

I tried your solution, but the result is the same :(